# How to check a bulk image name that is match with the image name in CSV file by a program

Tags: php, csv

Suppose I have 300 pieces of image file(xxxxxx.jpg) in a folder called "images", and I have a CSV file with 300 rows, each row of the first cell has a image name.

How can I check if all of the image name of image in folder "images" is match with the name in CSV file?

I have a little bit knowledge of PHP, so is it possible to write a little program in PHP to achieve this requirement. Could someone advise the idea/concept of this program?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with file handing and string manipulation in PHP, refer below links for better understanding.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filesystem.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_string.asp

Comment: I would submit **[w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)** for your perusal. Stop the madness ...